# not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster

Tags: typescript, amazon-eks, aws-cdk, roles, policies

after cdk deploy:

```
cdkDeploy--dev--ClusterEKS/cdkDeploy--dev--ClusterEKS/Resource/Resource/Default (cdkDeploydevClusterEKS37F9DAF6)
 Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned:
 User: arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/cdkDeploystack1-cdkDeploydevClusterEKSCreationRole-1FNO2560SPCWP/AWSCDK.EKSCluster.Create.dbee9f9e-a956-4340-bf11-381d24d7b789 
is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:<account_id>:cluster/*
```

I've been learning about cdk infraestructure such a code. i want to implement a EKS cluster with my security group using autoScalling eks, nodeGroup, vpc, ECR with CD/CI codeBuild, and more tools... but i've been stacking several days in the same "not authorized error"... i created Role, with Policies statements with EKS:* but nothing, nothing works for some weird problem... i dont know what is wrong if i used the role with the right policies.

i had exported that bastionHostPolicies with eksadministrator  PolicyStatement using "eks:*" action for all resources "*".

```
           const statements = [
              new iam.PolicyStatement({
                effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                actions: ['ec2:*'],
                resources: ['*'],
                sid: 'EC2ALL',
              }),
              new PolicyStatement({
                resources: [
                  '*'
                ],
                actions: [
                  "eks:*"
                ],
                effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                sid: 'eksadministrator',
              }),
              new PolicyStatement({
                resources: ['*'],
                actions: [
                    'autoscaling:*'
                ],
                effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                sid: 'AutoScalingALL',
              }),
              new PolicyStatement({
                  effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                  actions: [
                    'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken',
                    'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability',
                    'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer',
                    'ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy',
                    'ecr:DescribeRepositories',
                    'ecr:ListImages',
                    'ecr:DescribeImages',
                    'ecr:BatchGetImage',
                    'ecr:ListTagsForResource',
                    'ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings',
                    'ecr:InitiateLayerUpload',
                    'ecr:UploadLayerPart',
                    'ecr:CompleteLayerUpload',
                    'ecr:PutImage',
                    'ecr:CreateRepository',
                  ],
                  resources: ['*'],
                  sid: 'ECRALL',
              }),
              new PolicyStatement({
                effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                actions: [
                  "s3:CreateBucket",  
                  "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",  
                  "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                ],
                resources: [
                  '*',
                  "arn:aws:s3:::*"
                ],
                sid: 'S3All',
              }),
              new PolicyStatement({
                resources: ['*'],
                actions: ['ssm:*'],
                sid: 'ssmALL'
              }),
              new PolicyStatement({
                resources: ['*'],
                actions: ['iam:*'],
                sid: 'iamALL'
              })
            ];
           this.bastionHostPolicies = new iam.PolicyDocument({
             statements,
           })
```

```
import { Fn, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import {Construct} from 'constructs';
import { getString } from '../../utils';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Key } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-kms';
import * as eks from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-eks';
import { propsCustomEKS } from '../interfaces';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as autoscaling from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-autoscaling';
const helper = require('js-yaml');
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam'
import { KubectlV27Layer } from '@aws-cdk/lambda-layer-kubectl-v27';
/** Class representing a vpc import from parameter stores
 * with a predefine sysntax name
 *  */
class CustomEKS  extends Construct {
    public readonly cluster: eks.Cluster
    public readonly awsauth: eks.AwsAuth
    public readonly asg: autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup
    public readonly clusterKmsKey: Key;
     constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, projectProps: propsCustomEKS ) {
     super(scope, id);
     const {vpc, bastionHostPolicies, securityGroup} = projectProps;
     
       this.clusterKmsKey = new Key(
        this, 
        `ekskmskey`, 
        {
        enableKeyRotation: true,
        alias: cdk.Fn.join('', ['alias/', 'eks/', `ekskmskey`]),
      });
      const eksRole = new iam.Role(this, 'EksClusterMasterRole', {
        assumedBy: new iam.AccountRootPrincipal(),
        managedPolicies: [
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonEKSServicePolicy"),
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"),
        ],
        inlinePolicies: { bastionHostPolicies }
      });
      this.cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/ClusterEKS`, {
        defaultCapacity: 0,  // we want to manage capacity our selves
        version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_27,
        kubectlLayer: new KubectlV27Layer(this, 'kubectl'),
        endpointAccess: eks.EndpointAccess.PRIVATE,
        secretsEncryptionKey: this.clusterKmsKey,
        mastersRole: eksRole,
        securityGroup,
        clusterName: `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/ClusterEKS`,
        placeClusterHandlerInVpc: true,
        vpc: vpc.vpc,
        vpcSubnets: [vpc.vpc.selectSubnets({
          subnets: vpc.subn,
          onePerAz: true,
        })],
      });

      const nodegroupRole = new iam.Role(scope, 'NodegroupRole', {
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("ec2.amazonaws.com"),
        managedPolicies: [
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"),
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"),
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"),
        ],
        inlinePolicies: {bastionHostPolicies}
      });

      this.cluster.addNodegroupCapacity("managed-node", {
        instanceTypes: [ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO)],
        minSize: 1,
        maxSize: 1,
        nodeRole: nodegroupRole
      });

      console.log('pasó eks clouster creation');
      
      this.asg = this.cluster.addAutoScalingGroupCapacity(
        `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/AutoScalingGroupEKS`, 
        {
        keyName: 'keypemToConnect',
        instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
        machineImageType: eks.MachineImageType.BOTTLEROCKET,
        autoScalingGroupName: `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/AutoScalingGroupEKS`,
        allowAllOutbound: false,
        healthCheck: autoscaling.HealthCheck.ec2(),
        minCapacity: 2,
        maxCapacity: 4,
        vpcSubnets: vpc.vpc.selectSubnets({
          subnets: vpc.subn,
          onePerAz: true,
        }),
      })
      console.log('autoScalling pass');

      this.asg.connections.allowTo(this.cluster, ec2.Port.tcp(443), 'Allow between BastionHost and EKS ');
     
      this.asg.userData.addCommands(
        `VERSION=$(aws --region ${projectProps.region} eks describe-cluster --name ${this.cluster.clusterName} --query 'cluster.version' --output text)`,
        'echo \'K8s version is $VERSION\'',
        'curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/v$VERSION.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl',
        'install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /bin/kubectl',
      );
         
      this.awsauth = new eks.AwsAuth(this, 'EKS_AWSAUTH', {
        cluster: this.cluster,
      });

      this.cluster.awsAuth.addRoleMapping(eksRole, { groups: [ 'system:masters' ]});

      this.cluster.awsAuth.addMastersRole(eksRole);
    
    }
     

}

export  { CustomEKS }
```

i want to create a eks cluster but i've been stack in the same error even using the role with the right policies...

also my main user aws account has that same policies eks:
[eks permissions policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4El3.png)

cloudwatch log error:

```
2023-08-27T20:21:56.254Z    c23b4123-a8ec-4679-a48f-fd444d3f9aa6    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
    "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/cdkDeploystack1-cdkDeploydevClusterEKSCreationRole-XST49HASZHMH/AWSCDK.EKSCluster.Create.21debcdd-8c24-44de-9f70-3eb132bd8288 is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:<account_id>:cluster/*",
    "name": "AccessDeniedException",
    "$fault": "client",
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 403,
        "requestId": "049f0b1c-fb7e-416f-b3e1-f586f2f3a2b7",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "message": "User: arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/cdkDeploystack1-cdkDeploydevClusterEKSCreationRole-XST49HASZHMH/AWSCDK.EKSCluster.Create.21debcdd-8c24-44de-9f70-3eb132bd8288 is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:<account_id>:cluster/*",
    "stack": [
        "AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/cdkDeploystack1-cdkDeploydevClusterEKSCreationRole-XST49HASZHMH/AWSCDK.EKSCluster.Create.21debcdd-8c24-44de-9f70-3eb132bd8288 is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:<account_id>:cluster/*",
        "    at throwDefaultError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)",
        "    at deserializeAws_restJson1CreateClusterCommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-eks/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restJson1.js:1035:51)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/middleware.js:13:20",
        "    at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/StandardRetryStrategy.js:51:46)",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22",
        "    at async ClusterResourceHandler.onCreate (/var/task/cluster.js:1:1028)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The role you are creating is the masters role, and it is not related to the role that creates the cluster. There is probably a permissions boundary or a org-wide SCP preventing the Creation role to create the cluster.

Comment: I would have a look at the examples here, https://github.com/aws-quickstart/cdk-eks-blueprints

Comment: Thaks you guys for reply. Is my personal account aws that i've been using... but dear gshpychka i dont understood your explain about  " There is probably a permissions boundary or a org-wide SCP preventing the Creation role to create the cluster" what i have to do about that? if you can see the fragment "also my main user aws account has that same policies eks: eks permissions policy" that is the screenshot about the deploy main role CDK from my main user aws.